# Strophe & Ejabberd: problem with reauthentication after sending message

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

Im using Strophe attach method to connect to ejabberd (2.1.6) with external authentication. Everything works fine after attaching, but when I'm trying to send a message stanza to some user, that user does not recieve his message. Message stanza is stored in spool table in database. I don't know why the message isnt delivered directly to the user.

The only thing I see in ejabberd log is that after sending message ejabberd is testing user to whom I sent the message with external isuser call, and after that ejabberd reauthenticates me.

I don't know if that reauthentication is normal thing or there's something out there that I do wrong.

Do any of you had this type of problem before? If so, how did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it the sender that is getting reauthenticated?  If so, it's possible that you're sending XML that is not well-formed, and the server is disconnecting you.

Comment: Yes, it's the sender. The message stanza the client is sending is formed the way the Strophe library used to form it with standard $msg function.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there was a problem with my app and htaccess file which sent all requests to index.php if the resource was not a directory or a file, which caused my app to once again run GET request if there was an image that did not exist on server, but was included in html.
And because I was connecting to ejabberd on every request (except for ajax) reauthentication was taking place.
Than you for your interest.